# Multiple nginx subdomains leads to a single jetty instance

Tags: nginx, jenkins, jetty, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have added multiple subdomains on nginx and now I would like to proxy pass all subdomains to a single jetty instance.

Let´s say
subdomain1.blog.com -> localhost:8080/subdomain1
jenkins.blog.com -> localhost:8080/jenkins

I tested a lot of examples and in the end I struggled with the url.
If I open http://jenkins.blog.com I will redirect to https://jenkins.blog.com/jenkins/login?from=%2Fjenkins%2F

How can I get rid of this /jenkins/ in my url?
Is it possible to achieve it without using multiple jetty instances and deploying apps on webroot?

```
upstream jetty {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name jenkins.blog.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name jenkins.blog.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/blog.com-0002/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/blog.com-0002/privkey.pem;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;


   location /jenkins {
     rewrite ^/jenkins(/.*)$ $1 last;
   }


    location / {
      proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      # Fix the "It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
      proxy_pass       http://jetty/jenkins/;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;

      #proxy_redirect      http://localhost:8080/jenkins    https://jenkins.blog.com;
      #proxy_redirect      http:// https://;

      proxy_redirect       off;
      proxy_buffering      off;
      # Required for new HTTP-based CLI
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_request_buffering off;
      # workaround for https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45651
      add_header 'X-SSH-Endpoint' 'jenkins.blog.com:50022' always;     
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you setup virtualhosts on your Jetty side yet?

Comment: Yes, I tried it, but my jetty isn't public and was always failing with really unclear errors. In my understanding I should be able to add a jenkings.blog.com vhost on jetty and a another vhost for subdomain.2.blog.com. Then I should be able to access port 8080 from outside right?